# Cast IEnumerable<T> to ObservableCollection<T> without constructor injection the IEnumerable<T>

Tags: ienumerable, observablecollection, casting

How can I do that?

thats a no go:

ObservableCollection obsCol = new  ObservableCollection(myIEnumerable);

scenario:

```
var query = from c in customers
                    select new Customer()
                    {
                       Products = from p in products
                                  where p.Id = c.Id
                                  select p
};
```

Products is a ObservableCollection so it can not take the IEnumerable result from the select above...

How to cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
ObservableCollection obsCol = new ObservableCollection(myIEnumerable.ToList());
```

Note that the `ObservableCollection` instance will not reflect changes to the `customers` list.

**EDIT**: The Select extension method returns an instance of a compiler-generated iterator class. Since this class does not inherit `ObservableCollection`, it is impossible to cast it to one.

Comment: please read about my no go statement and then edit your answer, thanks.

Comment: @msfanboy: It is, by definition, completely impossible to do this in any other way.  Please read about casting and classes and then edit your question, thanks.

Comment: The `Select` extension method returns an instance of a compiler-generated iterator class.  Since this class does not inherit `ObservableCollection`, it is impossible to cast it to one.

Comment: @SLaks I would mark your last comment as answer if you would put it in an answer... :)

seems Linq + IEnumerable + ObservableCollection + aggregating business objects are a bad choice...

Comment: @msfanboy: Here you go.  Note that there is nothing wrong with writing `new ObservableCollection`.  It's not a bad choice, and it can work perfectly fine. (As long as you understand what the change events come from)

Comment: of course there is nothing wrong with "new ObservableCollection" alone, never said that I used another context.